# Trying to run a Vaadin Project in IntellijIdea using gwt-graphics-1.0.0 jar file

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I am getting the below error when i am running my project which will drag a text and drop on an image.

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Vaadin threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2446)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2756)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1693)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServletPortletHelper.verifyUIClass(ServletPortletHelper.java:75)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServletPortletHelper.initDefaultUIProvider(ServletPortletHelper.java:139)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.createAndRegisterSession(VaadinService.java:764)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.doFindOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:718)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:659)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:518)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1396)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT Graphics is a GWT library, which means that it doesn't work with the server-side API of Vaadin. If you want to use it with Vaadin, you need to create your own component, and use GWT Graphics on the client side of that component.